# Wacky Linked List behavior Java Eclipse Mars.1

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list

The full code is a 2-3 tree implementation that requires me to be able to search for a book by any key(ISSN, Author[0], Author[1], Author[0] + "," + Author[1], or Title) The tree works by creating 5 copies of each book, each designated with one of the keys previously mentioned, and inserting them into their respective leaves. If a new book being inserted matches a key that has already been inserted into the tree (ie., James Henry, and James Joyce both would have a copy of their books inserted into the tree with key "james"), then instead of that new book being added into a leaf node at the bottom of the tree, it is added into a linked list inside of the node that already contains a copy all books with key == "james".

Class Tree23:

```
package tree23;

import bookClasses.*;

/**
 * @author Chris
 * @usage This Class builds a 2-3 tree that sorts Book entries based on ISSN value
 */
 public class Tree23 {
    public Node23 Root;


                // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS //
    public Tree23(){
        Root = new Node23(true);
    }

    public void Insert(int issn, String title, String author){
        String issnKey = null;
        String titleKey = null;
        String authorKey = null;
        String author0Key = null;
        String author1Key = null;

        issnKey = String.valueOf(issn);
        titleKey = title.toLowerCase();
        authorKey = author.toLowerCase();
        if(author.split(",").length == 2){
            author0Key = author.split(",")[0].toLowerCase();
            author1Key = author.split(",")[1].toLowerCase();
        }

        Book[] newBooks = new Book[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            newBooks[i] = new Book(issn, title, author);
        }


        InsertByKey(newBooks[0], issnKey);
        InsertByKey(newBooks[1], titleKey);
        InsertByKey(newBooks[2], authorKey);
        if(author.split(",").length == 2){
            InsertByKey(newBooks[3], author0Key);
            InsertByKey(newBooks[4], author1Key);
        }
    }


    public BookList GetBooksByAttribute(char attribute, String key){
        BookList matches = null;
        switch(attribute){
            case 'i':
                matches = GetBooksByISSN(Integer.valueOf(key));
                break;
            case 'n':
                matches = GetBooksByAuthor(key.toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 't':
                matches = GetBooksByTitle(key.toLowerCase());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return matches;
    }

            // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS //
    /*Insert Functions*/
    private void InsertByKey(Book newBook, String key){
        if(key.compareTo("james") == 0){
            if(newBook.Title.toLowerCase().compareTo("finnegans wake") == 0){
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }
        //check for a node with matching key
        Node23 targetNode = GetNodeByKey(Root, key);
        //else find leaf for insert
        if(targetNode == null){
            targetNode = GetLeafByKey(Root, key);
        }       
        //insert into target node
        targetNode.AddBook(newBook, key);
        if(key.compareTo("james") == 0){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        if(targetNode.GetSize() == 3){
            BalanceNodeOverflow(targetNode);
        }       
    }

    /*Search Functions*/
    private BookList GetBooksByKey(Node23 n, String key){
        BookList bList = null;
        int match = n.GetMatchingBookListByKey(key);
        if(match != -1){
            bList = n.Books[match];
        }
        else{
            int nextChild = DetermineNextTraversal(n, key);
            bList = GetBooksByKey(n.Children[nextChild], key);
        }
        return bList;
    }

    private Node23 GetSuccessorLeaf(Node23 n, int index){
        Node23 leaf = n.Children[index + 1];
        while(!leaf.IsLeaf()){
            leaf = leaf.Children[0];
        }
        return leaf;
    }

    private BookList GetBooksByISSN(int issn){
        BookList keyMatches = GetBooksByKey(Root, String.valueOf(issn));
        BookList issnMatches = null;
        if(keyMatches != null){
            issnMatches = keyMatches.GetBooksByISSN(issn);
        }
        return  issnMatches;
    }

    private BookList GetBooksByAuthor(String author){
        BookList keyMatches = GetBooksByKey(Root, String.valueOf(author));
        BookList authorMatches = null;
        if(keyMatches != null){
            authorMatches = keyMatches.GetBooksByAuthor(author);
        }
        return authorMatches;
    }

    private BookList GetBooksByTitle(String title){
        BookList keyMatches = GetBooksByKey(Root, String.valueOf(title));
        BookList titleMatches = null;
        if(keyMatches != null){
            titleMatches = keyMatches.GetBooksByTitle(title);
        }
        return titleMatches;
    }

    private Node23 GetLeafByKey(Node23 n, String key){
        //assumes that there is no node matching key, traverses from root to leaf node by key
        //return key
        Node23 leaf = n;
        if(!n.IsLeaf()){
            int nextChild = n.GetNextChildByKey(key);
            leaf = GetLeafByKey(n.Children[nextChild], key);
        }
        return leaf;
    }

    private Node23 GetNodeByKey(Node23 n, String key){
        Node23 match = null;
        int nextChild;
        int matchingBookList = n.GetMatchingBookListByKey(key);
        if(matchingBookList >= 0){
            match = n;
        }
        else{
            nextChild = n.GetNextChildByKey(key);
            if(nextChild != -1){
                match = GetNodeByKey(n.Children[nextChild], key);
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    private int DetermineNextTraversal(Node23 n, String key){
        int nextChild;
        if(n.IsLeaf()){
            nextChild = -1;
        }
        else if(n.GetSize() == 0){
            nextChild = -1;
        }
        else if(n.GetSize() == 1){
            if(n.Books[0].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                nextChild = 0;
            }
            else{
                nextChild = 1;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(n.Books[0].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                nextChild = 0;
            }
            else if(n.Books[1].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                nextChild = 1;
            }
            else{
                nextChild = 2;
            }
        }
        return nextChild;
    }

    /*Delete Functions*/
    private void DeleteBookFromTree(Book b){
        Node23 match;
        int originalSize;
        /*findNodeMatchingISSN*/
        match = GetNodeByKey(Root, String.valueOf(b.ISSN));
        originalSize = match.GetSize();
        match.RemoveMatchingBook(b, String.valueOf(b.ISSN));
        if(originalSize > match.GetSize()){
            BalanceNodeUnderflow(match);
        }

        /*author[0]*/
        match = GetNodeByKey(Root, b.Author[0]);
        originalSize = match.GetSize();
        match.RemoveMatchingBook(b, b.Author[0]);
        if(originalSize > match.GetSize()){
            BalanceNodeUnderflow(match);
        }

        if(b.Author.length == 2){
            /*author[1]*/
            match = GetNodeByKey(Root, b.Author[1]);
            originalSize = match.GetSize();
            match.RemoveMatchingBook(b, b.Author[1]);
            if(originalSize > match.GetSize()){
                BalanceNodeUnderflow(match);
            }

            /*author[0],author[1]*/
            match = GetNodeByKey(Root, new String(b.Author[1] + "," + b.Author[2]));
            originalSize = match.GetSize();
            match.RemoveMatchingBook(b, new String(b.Author[1] + "," + b.Author[2]));
            if(originalSize > match.GetSize()){
                BalanceNodeUnderflow(match);
            }
        }

        /*title*/
        match = GetNodeByKey(Root, b.Title);
        originalSize = match.GetSize();
        match.RemoveMatchingBook(b, b.Author[1]);
        if(originalSize > match.GetSize()){
            BalanceNodeUnderflow(match);
        }
    }


    /*Tree Balancing Functions*/
    private void BalanceNodeOverflow(Node23 fullNode){  
        Node23[] splitNodes;
        if(fullNode == Root){
            Node23 newRoot = new Node23(false);
            fullNode.Parent = newRoot;
            splitNodes = fullNode.SplitNode();
            fullNode.Parent.AddBookList(fullNode.RemoveBookList(0));;
            newRoot.AddSplitNodeChildAt(0, splitNodes);
            Root = newRoot;
        }
        else{
            int position = fullNode.WhichChildAmI();
            splitNodes = fullNode.SplitNode();
            fullNode.Parent.AddBookList(fullNode.RemoveBookList(0));
            fullNode.Parent.AddSplitNodeChildAt(position, splitNodes);
            if(fullNode.Parent.GetSize() == 3){
                BalanceNodeOverflow(fullNode.Parent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RotateLeft1To0(Node23 parent){
        Node23[] children = parent.Children;
        children[0].AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(0));
        parent.AddBookList(children[1].RemoveBookList(0));
        children[1].ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
    }

    private void RotateLeft2To1(Node23 parent){
        Node23[] children = parent.Children;
        children[1].AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(1));
        parent.AddBookList(children[2].RemoveBookList(0));
        children[2].ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
    }

    private void RotateRight0To1(Node23 parent){
        Node23[] children = parent.Children;
        children[1].AddBookList(parent.RemoveLeftMostBookList());
        parent.AddBookList(children[0].RemoveRightMostBookList());
    }

    private void RotateRight1To2(Node23 parent){
        Node23[] children = parent.Children;
        children[2].AddBookList(parent.RemoveRightMostBookList());
        parent.AddBookList(children[1].RemoveRightMostBookList());
    }

    private void BalanceNodeUnderflow(Node23 n){
        Node23 leaf;
        int emptyPosition = n.FirstNullBookList();
        if(!n.IsLeaf()){
            leaf = GetSuccessorLeaf(n, emptyPosition);
            n.AddBookList(leaf.RemoveBookList(0));
        }
        else{
            leaf = n;
        }
        if(leaf.GetSize() == 0){
            FillHole(leaf);
        }
    }

    private void RedistributeParent3(Node23 hole, int holePosition){
        Node23 parent = hole.Parent;
        Node23[] siblings = parent.Children;
        switch(holePosition){
            case 0:
                if(siblings[1].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateLeft1To0(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        hole.AddChildAt(1, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].ShiftChildrenLeftInto(0);
                    }
                }
                else if(siblings[2].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateLeft1To0(parent);
                    RotateLeft2To1(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        hole.AddChildAt(1, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].ShiftChildrenLeftInto(0);
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(1, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[2].ShiftChildrenLeftInto(0);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    RotateLeft1To0(parent);
                    hole.AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(0));
                    parent.ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
                    siblings[1].AddBookList(siblings[2].RemoveBookList(0));
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        hole.AddChildAt(1, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].ShiftChildrenLeftInto(0);
                        hole.AddChildAt(2, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(0, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(1, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                    }
                    parent.RemoveRightMostChild();
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(siblings[0].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateRight0To1(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[1].ShiftChildrenRightInto(1);
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(0, siblings[0].RemoveRightMostChild());
                    }
                }
                else if(siblings[2].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateLeft2To1(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(1, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[2].ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    RotateLeft2To1(parent);
                    siblings[1].ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
                    RotateLeft1To0(parent);
                    parent.ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[0].AddChildAt(2, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(0, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(1, siblings[2].RemoveRightMostChild());
                    }
                    parent.RemoveRightMostChild();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(siblings[0].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateRight1To2(parent);
                    RotateRight0To1(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[2].ShiftChildrenRightInto(1);
                        siblings[2].AddChildAt(0, siblings[1].RemoveRightMostChild());
                        siblings[1].ShiftBooksRightInto(1);
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(0, siblings[0].RemoveRightMostChild());
                    }
                }
                else if(siblings[1].GetSize() == 2){
                    RotateRight1To2(parent);
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[2].ShiftChildrenRightInto(1);
                        siblings[2].AddChildAt(0, siblings[1].RemoveRightMostChild());
                    }
                }
                else{
                    RotateLeft1To0(parent);
                    siblings[1].AddBookList(parent.RemoveRightMostBookList());
                    if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
                        siblings[0].AddChildAt(2, siblings[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                        siblings[1].ShiftChildrenLeftInto(0);
                        siblings[1].AddChildAt(1, siblings[2].RemoveLeftMostChild());
                    }
                    parent.RemoveRightMostChild();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RedistributeParent2(Node23 hole, int holePosition){
        Node23 parent = hole.Parent;
        Node23[] siblings = parent.Children;
        switch(holePosition){
            case 0:
                hole.AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(0));
                parent.AddBookList(siblings[1].RemoveBookList(0));
                siblings[1].ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                hole.AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(0));
                parent.AddBookList(siblings[0].RemoveBookList(1));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Merge(Node23 hole, int holePosition){
        Node23 parent = hole.Parent;
        Node23[] sibling = parent.Children;

        if(holePosition == 0){
            sibling[0].AddBookList(sibling[1].RemoveBookList(0));
        }

        sibling[0].AddBookList(parent.RemoveBookList(0));
        if(!hole.IsLeaf()){
            sibling[0].AddChildAt(1, sibling[1].RemoveLeftMostChild());
            sibling[0].AddChildAt(2, sibling[1].RemoveRightMostChild());
        }
        parent.RemoveRightMostChild();
        if(parent.GetSize() == 0){
            BalanceNodeUnderflow(parent);
        }
    }

    private void FillHole(Node23 hole){
        Node23[] siblings;
        Node23 parent;
        int holePosition;

        if(hole == Root){
            Root = hole.Children[0];
        }else{
            parent = hole.Parent;
            siblings = parent.Children;
            holePosition = hole.WhichChildAmI();
            if(parent.GetSize() == 2){
                RedistributeParent3(hole, holePosition);
            }
            else{
                if(siblings[0].GetSize() == 2 || siblings[1].GetSize() == 2){
                    RedistributeParent2(hole, holePosition);
                }else{
                    Merge(hole, holePosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

package tree23;

import bookClasses.*;

/**
 * @Node
 *This Node is designed for a 2-3 Tree. 
 *The Node holds two Book objects and points to three children nodes of the same type.
 *The node is also designed to hold an overflow Book and overflow child, until the node is split.
 */

```
public class Node23 {
    public BookList[] Books;

    private boolean isLeaf;
    private int size;

    public Node23 Parent;
    public Node23[] Children;

    //Constructors
    public Node23(boolean isleaf){
        Books = new BookList[3];
        Children = new Node23[4];
        isLeaf = isleaf;
        size = 0;
    }

    public Node23[] SplitNode(){
        Node23[] splitNodes = new Node23[2];
        splitNodes[0] = new Node23(isLeaf);
        splitNodes[1] = new Node23(isLeaf);
        splitNodes[0].Parent = Parent;
        splitNodes[1].Parent = Parent;
        splitNodes[0].AddBookList(RemoveLeftMostBookList());
        splitNodes[1].AddBookList(RemoveRightMostBookList());
        if(!isLeaf){    
            Children[0].Parent = splitNodes[0];
            Children[1].Parent = splitNodes[0];
            splitNodes[0].Children[0] = Children[0];
            splitNodes[0].Children[1] = Children[1];
            Children[2].Parent = splitNodes[1];
            Children[3].Parent = splitNodes[1];
            splitNodes[1].Children[0] = Children[2];
            splitNodes[1].Children[1] = Children[3];

        }
        return splitNodes;
    }


    //Book Functions
    public int FirstNullBookList(){
        int emptyPos = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            if(Books[i] == null){
                emptyPos = -1;
            }
        }
        return emptyPos;
    }

    public int GetNextChildByKey(String key){       
        int nextChild = -1;
        if(!isLeaf){
            if(size == 1){
                if(Books[0].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                    nextChild = 0;
                }
                else{
                    nextChild = 1;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(Books[0].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                    nextChild = 0;
                }
                else if(Books[1].CompareTo(key) > 0){
                    nextChild = 1;
                }
                else{
                    nextChild = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return nextChild;
    }

    public int GetMatchingBookListByKey(String key){
        int match = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(Books[i].CompareTo(key) == 0)
                match = i;
        }
        return match;
    }

    public void TakeAllBookLists(Node23 n){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(n.Books[i] != null){
                AddBookList(n.RemoveBookList(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShiftBooksRightFrom(int shiftStart){
        for(int i = 2; i > shiftStart; i--){
            Books[i] = Books[i - 1];
        }
        Books[shiftStart] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftBooksRightInto(int shiftEnd){
        for(int i = shiftEnd; i > 0; i--){
            Books[i] = Books[i - 1];
        }
        Books[0] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftBooksLeftFrom(int shiftStart){
        for(int i = 0; i < shiftStart; i++){
            Books[i] = Books[i+1];
        }
        Books[shiftStart] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftBooksLeftInto(int shiftEnd){
        for(int i = shiftEnd; i < 2; i++){
            Books[i] = Books[i + 1];
        }
        Books[2] = null;
    }

    public void AddBookList(BookList newBookList){
        if(size == 0){
            Books[0] = newBookList;
        }
        else{
            if(newBookList.CompareTo(Books[0]) < 0){
                    ShiftBooksRightFrom(0);
                    Books[0] = newBookList;
            }
            else{
                if(size == 1){
                    Books[1] = newBookList;
                }
                else{
                    if(newBookList.CompareTo(Books[1]) < 0){
                        ShiftBooksRightFrom(1);
                        Books[1] = newBookList;
                    }
                    else{
                        Books[2] = newBookList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void AddBook(Book newBook, String key){
        if(size == 0){
            AddBookList(new BookList(newBook, key));
        }
        else{
            int match = GetMatchingBookListByKey(key);
            if(match != -1){
                Books[match].AddBook(newBook);
            }
            else{
                AddBookList(new BookList(newBook, key));
            }
        }       
    }

    public BookList RemoveRightMostBookList(){
        BookList bList = null;
        for(int i = 2; i > 0; i--){
            if(Books[i] != null){
                bList = Books[i];
                Books[i] = null;
                size--;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bList;   
    }

    public BookList RemoveLeftMostBookList(){
        BookList bList = null;
        bList = Books[0];
        ShiftBooksLeftInto(0);
        size--;
        return bList;
    }

    public BookList RemoveBookList(int position){
        BookList bList = Books[position];
        ShiftBooksLeftInto(position);
        size--;
        return bList;
    }

    public void RemoveMatchingBook(Book b, String key){
        if(Books[0] != null){
            if(Books[0].CompareTo(key) == 0){
                Books[0].DeleteBooksByISSN(b.ISSN);
            }
        }
        else if(Books[1] != null){
            if(Books[1].CompareTo(key) == 0){
                Books[1].DeleteBooksByISSN(b.ISSN);
            }
        }
        else if(Books[2] != null){
            if(Books[2].CompareTo(key) == 0){
                Books[2].DeleteBooksByISSN(b.ISSN);
            }
        }
    }


    //Child-Node Functions
    public Node23 RemoveLeftMostChild(){
        Node23 n = null;
        int i = 0;
        while(n == null && i <= 3){
            if(Children[i] != null){
                n = Children[i];
                Children[i] = null;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public Node23 RemoveRightMostChild(){
        Node23 n = null;
        int i = 3;
        while(n == null && i >= 0 ){
            if(Children[i] != null){
                n = Children[i];
                Children[i] = null;
            }
            i--;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public void AddChildAt(int index, Node23 newChildNode){
        Children[index] = newChildNode;
    }

    public void AddSplitNodeChildAt(int position, Node23[] splitNode){
        ShiftChildrenRightFrom(position + 1);
        AddChildAt(position, splitNode[0]);
        AddChildAt(position + 1, splitNode[1]);
    }


    public void ShiftChildrenRightFrom(int shiftStart){
        for(int i = 3; i > shiftStart; i--){
            Children[i] = Children[i - 1];
        }
        Children[shiftStart] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftChildrenRightInto(int shiftEnd){
        for(int i = shiftEnd; i > 0; i--){
            Children[i] = Children[i - 1];
        }
        Children[0] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftChildrenLeftFrom(int shiftStart){
        for(int i = 0; i < shiftStart; i++){
            Children[i] = Children[i + 1];
        }
        Children[shiftStart] = null;
    }

    public void ShiftChildrenLeftInto(int shiftEnd){
        for(int i = shiftEnd; i < 2; i++){
            Children[i] = Children[i + 1];
        }
        Children[2] = null;
    }



    //Attribute Functions

    public int CountChildren(){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(Children[i] != null){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean IsRoot(){
        boolean isRoot = false;
        if(Parent == null){
            isRoot = true;
        }
        return isRoot;
    }


    public int WhichChildAmI(){
        int childNum = -1;
        if(!IsRoot()){
            for(int i = 0; i < Parent.size + 1; i++){
                if(Parent.Children[i] == this){
                    childNum = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return childNum;
    }

    public boolean IsLeaf(){
        return isLeaf;
    }

    public int GetSize(){
        return size;
    }

}
```

Class Book: This is the Book class that makes the links of the linked list within each Node23

```
package bookClasses;

public class Book{
    public int ISSN;
    public String Title;
    public String[] Author;
    public Book Next;

    public Book(){}

    /**
     * @param ISSN
     * @param Title
     * @param Author
     */
    public Book(int issn, String title, String author){
        ISSN = issn;
        Title = title;
        Author = author.split(",");
        Next = null;
    }


    private String AuthorToString(){
        String author = Author[0];
        if(Author.length == 2){
            author = author + ", " + Author[1];
        }
        return author;
    }

    public void Display(){
        System.out.println("\tISSN: " + ISSN);
        System.out.println("\tTITLE: " + Title);
        System.out.println("\tAUTHOR: " + AuthorToString());
    }

    public boolean MatchAuthor(String author){
        boolean match = false;
        if(Author.length == 2){
            if(author.compareTo(Author[0].toLowerCase()) == 0 
                    || author.compareTo(Author[1].toLowerCase()) == 0){
                match = true;
            }
        }
        if(author.split(",") == Author){
            match = true;
        }
        return match;
    }

}
```

Class BookList: This is the linked List inside of each node containing copies all books with a matching key

```
package bookClasses;

public class BookList {
    public String Key;
    public Book Head;
    private int Size;

    public BookList(){
        Head = null;
        Size = 0;
    };

    public BookList(Book b, String key){
        Size = 1;
        Key = key;
        Head = b;
    }

    //Insert Functions
    public void AddBook(Book newBook){  
        newBook.Next = Head;
        Head = newBook;
        Size++;
    }


    //Search Functions
    public BookList GetBooksByISSN(int issn){
        BookList books = new BookList();
        Book b = Head;
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            if(issn == b.ISSN){
                books.AddBook(b);
            }
        }
        return books;
    }

    public BookList GetBooksByTitle(String title){
        BookList matches = new BookList();
        Book b = Head;
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            if(title.compareTo(b.Title.toLowerCase()) == 0){
                matches.AddBook(b);
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }

    public BookList GetBooksByAuthor(String author){
        BookList books = new BookList();
        Book b = Head;
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            if(b.MatchAuthor(author)){
                books.AddBook(b);
            }
            b = b.Next;
        }
        return books;
    }

    //Delete Functions
    public void DeleteBooksByAuthor(String author){
        Book b = Head;
        if(b.MatchAuthor(author)){
            Head = b.Next;
            Size--;
        }
        else{
            while(b.Next != null){
                if(b.Next.MatchAuthor(author)){
                    b.Next = b.Next.Next;
                    Size--;
                }
                else{
                    b = b.Next;
                }
            }   
        }   
    }

    public void DeleteBooksByTitle(String title){
        Book b = Head;
        if(b.Title.toLowerCase().compareTo(title.toLowerCase()) == 0){
            Head = b.Next;
            Size--;
        }
        else{
            while(b.Next != null){
                if(b.Next.Title.toLowerCase().compareTo(title.toLowerCase()) == 0){
                    b.Next = b.Next.Next;
                    Size--;
                }
                else{
                    b = b.Next;
                }
            }   
        }   
    }

    public void DeleteBooksByISSN(int issn){
        Book b = Head;
        if(b.ISSN == issn){
            Head = b.Next;
            Size--;
        }
        else{
            while(b.Next != null){
                if(b.Next.ISSN == issn){
                    b.Next = b.Next.Next;
                    Size--;
                }
                else{
                    b = b.Next;
                }
            }   
        }   
    }


    //Other Methods
    public void Displayall(){
        Book b = Head;
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            b.Display();
            b = b.Next;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(BookList bookList){
        return (Key.compareTo(bookList.Key));
    }

    public int CompareTo(String key){
        return (Key.compareTo(key));
    }

    public int Size(){
        return Size;
    }
}
```

Heres the input file - the 1 specifies INSERT

```
1
60
The Black Dahlia
James,Ellroy
1
98
The Turn of the Screw
Henry,James
1
147
The Wings of the Dove
Henry,James
1
151
A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man
James,Joyce
1
157
The Postman Always Rings Twice
James,M.
1
184
How Late It Was, How Late
James,Kelman
1
186
A Disaffection
James,Kelman
1
320
The Ambassadors
Henry,James
1
326
What Maisie Knew
Henry,James
1
327
The Golden Bowl The Golden Bowl
Henry,James
1
353
The Charwoman's Daughter
James,Stephens
1
362
Ulysses
James,Joyce
1
478
Finnegans Wake
James,Joyce
```

After inserting ulysses

```
The Black Dahlia
The Turn of the Screw
The Wings of the Dove
A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man
The Postman Always Rings Twice
How Late It Was, How Late
A Disaffection
The Ambassadors
What Maisie Knew
The Golden Bowl The Golden Bowl
The Charwoman's Daughter
Ulysses <==Head
```

Now here's where it gets wacky: 
if I try and insert this entry:

```
478
Finnegans Wake
James,Joyce
```

bringing the size of the list from 12, to 13,
the new order of the list becomes:

```
    The Black Dahlia
    The Turn of the Screw
    The Wings of the Dove
    A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man
    The Postman Always Rings Twice
    How Late It Was, How Late
    A Disaffection
    The Ambassadors
    What Maisie Knew
    The Golden Bowl The Golden Bowl
    Ulysses 
    Finnegans Wake <=======HEAD
```

The Charwomans daughter has dissappeared. 
This change happens when Head = newBook;

Comment: Post a complete minimal reproducible test case. Why aren't you using a java.util.LinkedList, instead of redefining your own?

Comment: Who knows, can't see any of the relevant code. Unrelated, but not following Java naming conventions makes it a bit wonky to think about.

Comment: @JBNizet It's for a senior level Algorithms class. My professor is prefers we design our own data structures.

Comment: My apologies about the format @DaveNewton, but to address your difficulty making any assessment, when asking questions like this, Should I post a complete stack trace of the methods?

Comment: What you should show us is a complete program with the data so that we can run it and see what is wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton Full code shown now, excluding the main method, due to post-size limit. 
Main method calls Tree23.Insert(int ISSN, String Title, String Author);

Answer (score -1):

So, I thought it might have something to do with my hardware, and the computer I originally had this project stored on uses an AMD processor, so I got on my intel laptop and accessed the AMD desktop over the network. I copied the project file into my workspace on the laptop - Just a simple drag and drop. 
First I run the code on the intel laptop,, and as expected, it doesnt work, then I run the code on the desktop again, and NOW IT WORKS. No changes were made.
After the code worked on the desktop, it suddenly worked on the laptop.

Comment: Always assume the problem is in your own code. The chances of this being a hardware fault or a bug in the JVM are pretty much zero.

Comment: Essentially zero chance of the issue being processor-related.

Comment: (Or having anything to do with the steps you took.)

Comment: What would explain the code not working for dozens of runs, then on the next run working? There are no dependencies on external variables like time, or location, and the input comes from a text file that has not changed.
I'm not asserting that my speculations are true, or that your feedback is false, but if the code goes from broken to working, without making any changes in the code, is it that far from logical to speculate that the problem was something other than the code? I'm trying to be open-minded here, so I mean no disrespect. I'm sure you know this craft better than I do.

Comment: It's a *lot* more likely you weren't running the code you thought you were, had an IDE/environment issue, etc. It's clearly not a processor issue (and in 99.9999999999% of cases it never is), and it's clearly not a JDK issue (and in 99.99% of cases it isn't). I never said it was the code itself, and it's almost certainly not because you copied it from once machine to another.

Comment: That was another thought I had. I could imagine it being a bug in the IDE more than any other non-code issue, especially since the release version is still relatively new.